# How to push transactions dynamically in hashgraph?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, hashgraph, hedera-hashgraph

How to push transactions dynamically into run method of hash graph?

For instance:

In the below code, the name is published as a transaction. How to get this value dynamically. If it has to be through socket, which is the best place to initiate the socket?

```
public void run() {

    String myName = platform.getState().getAddressBookCopy().getAddress(selfId).getSelfName();

    console.out.println("Hello Swirld from " + myName);

    byte[] transaction = myName.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    platform.createTransaction(transaction, null);
    String lastReceived = "";

    while (true) {
        IPOSAppState state = (IPOSAppState) platform.getState();
        String received = state.getReceived();

        if (!lastReceived.equals(received)) {
            lastReceived = received;
            console.out.println("Received: " + received); // print all received transactions
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(sleepPeriod);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Any example code would really help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This project contains a demonstration of a web application communicating with a Swirld sdk.

https://github.com/craigdrabiktxmq/exo-demo

Answer (score 0):

We have more options with the new open source Hedera Hashgraph SDK. Hedera Hashgraph has implemented protocol buffers API for building contracts, cryptocurrencies, common utilities, file systems, services etc. You can find the details of the API below.

https://github.com/hashgraph/hedera-protobuf

There is a specific implementation of this API for transaction queries in the following example provided in this repository itself.

https://github.com/hashgraph/hedera-protobuf/blob/master/Transaction-Query-Examples.md

Hope this makes sense for your requirements.